# Saving object name in a new variable ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to dynamically get the name of "/dev/sda2" so i can use it as a variable for ansible to grow the partition. Since its random and can be either sda or sdb i.e.

Anyone know how i can dynamicly fetch it? The point is to get the device name that holds the "/" partition.

Im currently using:

```
- name: Display mount devices for root filesystem
  debug:
    msg: "{{ ansible_lvm.pvs }}"
  register: mount_devices_result
```

which prints the whole object, but i have a hard time to just get the device name, i.e (sda or sdb). Help is appriciated!

Comment: Can you update your question with the full output of `ansible_lvm` and or `ansible_lvm.pvs`? Without the data structure and content I am not sure how one could answer this.

Comment: Updated with full object of ansible_lvm! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your former provided sample data set, a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    ansible_lvm:
      pvs: { "/dev/sda2": '' }

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{  ansible_lvm.pvs.keys() | first }}"
```

will get all keys from the `ansible_lvm.pvs` dict as list and [filter the  first item of the sequence](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.first) only.

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: /dev/sda2
```

**Further Reading**

- [How to work with lists and dictionaries in Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-lists-dictionaries-yaml)
- [Using filters to manipulate data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the point is that we dont know if its sdA or sdB so this value needs to be fetched dynamicly based on what device holds the root partition.

Comment: "_we dont know if its sdA or sdB so this value needs to be fetched dynamicly_", that's exactly what the example is showing. "_based on what device holds the root partition_", can you explain this in more detail? And maybe provide your example data set again, which is deleted currently, but with a content of two discs?

Comment: My bad! I somehow didnt see your full response!